# Is there an simple way to swap the values of bits?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a 16-bit int, and I am trying to exchange the values of some of the individual bit components.

For instance:

> - swap the values of the 3rd and 4th bit.
> - swap the values of the 5th and 6th bit.

I also have to deal with more complicated chains of value transference.

> - move the value of the 2nd bit to the 3rd bit
> - move the value of the 3rd bit to the 1st bit
> - move the value of the 1st bit to the 4th bit
> - move the value of the 4th bit to the 2nd bit.

Is there a sensible way to do this? The bits aren't always adjacent, so a rotate doesn't seem particularly viable. Right now, all I can think to do is rebuild the int bit-by-bit (via successive &s + >>s), but that doesn't seem particularly effective.

I've got this right now:

```
            // bit 2 to bit 3
            temp_shape = 0;
            temp_shape = l_shape & NegXFace;
            temp_shape >>= 1;
            resultShape |= temp_shape;
            // bit 3 to bit 1
            temp_shape = 0;
            temp_shape = l_shape & PosYFace;
            temp_shape <<= 2;
            resultShape |= temp_shape;
            // bit 1 to bit 4
            temp_shape = 0;
            temp_shape = l_shape & PosXFace;
            temp_shape >>= 2;
            resultShape |= temp_shape;
            // bit 4 to bit 2
            temp_shape = 0;
            temp_shape = l_shape & PosYFace;
            temp_shape <<= 2;
            resultShape |= temp_shape;
            // bits 5 and 6
            temp_shape = 0;
            temp_shape = l_shape & (PosZFace | NegZFace);
            resultShape |= temp_shape;
```

Comment: What's the context for this question? Regardless of which bit ops you end up choosing, the compiler is likely to optimize it away anyways. Have you tested your slow solution to see if the compiler hasn't improved it in some way already? Is this homework?

Comment: @roliu It's for graphics, actually. The 6 bits represent the 6 faces of a cube, and the idea is to only render sides which can actually be seen. This works fine when your cube doesn't move, but I've recently added in the ability to rotate the cube, which means I need to interpret the 6 bits as different axis (hence the movement of bits, above).

Comment: Are you going to have to do this 10,000 times in a row?  If not, don't worry about optimization, just write a function to do it that is simple and clear as possible.

Comment: So have you actually run into performance issues? The compiler really takes care of this stuff. I don't know the details of C# compilers but I have strong doubts that you'd notice a difference between your "slow" solution and one that uses fewer bit ops.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear; I'm not trying to optimize, I'm having trouble determining how to actually write the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers were useful, none of the provided methods will work if you ever need to perform more than one of these bit swapping operations in sequence.

Once you've already moved the bits around, it becomes damn near impossible to know which bits started where, unless you want to write logic for every possible permutation of bit swappings.

Instead, you need a method that works for relative position (the bit position of what was originally the 2nd bit), rather than absolute position (the 2nd bit).

Here's how I would do it:

```
bool[] relFaces = new bool[6];
        bool swapBool;

        //start relFaces with the absolute faces.
        //default value of bool is "FALSE"
        if((l_shape & PosXFace) == PosXFace)
        {
            relFaces[0] = true;
        }
        if((l_shape & NegXFace) == NegXFace)
        {
            relFaces[1] = true;
        }
        if((l_shape & PosYFace) == PosYFace)
        {
            relFaces[2] = true;
        }
        if((l_shape & NegYFace) == NegYFace)
        {
            relFaces[3] = true;
        }
        if((l_shape & PosZFace) == PosZFace)
        {
            relFaces[4] = true;
        }
        if((l_shape & NegZFace) == NegZFace)
        {
            relFaces[5] = true;
        }


            // -z >> -x
            swapBool = relFaces[1];
            relFaces[1] = relFaces[5];
            // +x >> -z
            relFaces[5] = relFaces[0];
            // +z >> +X
            relFaces[0] = relFaces[4];
            // -X >> +z
            relFaces[4] = swapBool;
            break;
```

This code has the advantage of being much easier to understand at a glance, and you don't have to do further operations on bits you're not interested in changing. Finally, as mentioned earlier, this code will work for an arbitrary chain of successive bit-swaps, changing the relative facing (in your case) while maintaining the absolute facing as well.

Do note that you will have to rebuild `l_shape` once you're done swapping bits.

Answer (score 1):

well you can check to see if the bits are the same, and if they are the same do nothing.  And if they are different, you can flip both of them at the same time by XORing by the appropriate bit mask (eg 0001100 for 3rd and 4th bit).  I'm not really sure how "efficient" this will end up being though.

Comment: XOR is the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyBits
{ 
    Bit1 = 0x01,
    Bit2 = 0x02,
    Bit3 = 0x04,
    Bit4 = 0x08,
    Bit5 = 0x10,
    Bit6 = 0x20
}
```

Then:

```
public MyBits SwitchBits(MyBits oldBits)
{
    // Extracting every bits
    bool Bit1 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit1);
    bool Bit2 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit2);
    bool Bit3 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit3);
    bool Bit4 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit4);
    bool Bit5 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit5);
    bool Bit6 = oldBits.HasFlag(MyBits.Bit6);

    MyBits newBits = new MyBits();

    // Scrambling the bits
    if (Bit4) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit1;
    if (Bit2) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit2;
    if (Bit3) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit3;
    if (Bit1) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit4;
    if (Bit6) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit5;
    if (Bit5) newBits = newBits | MyBits.Bit6;

    return newBits ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function can easily swap bit positions pos1 and pos2 of a number n.
1st it checks that the two bits are different or not, if diffrent then it toggled from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1 and if same then it do nothing and simply return that number

```
int swap_bit(int n, int pos1, pos2)
{
 ((n >> pos1) & 1 ) != ( (n >> pos2) & 1 ) ? n = n ^ (( 1 << pos1) |( 1 << pos2)):n;

return n;  }
```