# How can i solve this problem using bitwise operators?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

The problem is: Write a program that swaps the bits on positions `{p, p+1,...,p+k-1}` with bits on positions `{q, q+1,...,q+k-1}` of a given integer.

Honestly, I don't know what the answer should be and therefore I don't know if my solution is remotely valid, but I've tried solving it using a nested for loop.

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = p; i < p + k - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = q; j < q + k - 1; j++)
        {
            int bitP = (n >> p) & 1;
            int bitQ = (n >> q) & 1;
            n = n & (~(1 << q)) | (p << q);
            n = n & (~(1 << p)) | (q << p);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: It appears as though your teacher wants you to take a single integer ("of a given integer") and use bitwise operators to swap the positions of certain bits in that integer. I suggest doing some research on "swapping positions of bits in integer in c#", which brought up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13328636/215552) almost immediately.

Comment: Hint: you only need **one** `for` --> `for(int i=0; i<k; i++){ // use p+i and q+i }`. Note: you currently don't even **use** `i` or `j`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you only need one `for` loop.
Second, you need to use the loop index value.

See code below:

```
static void Main()
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        // get binary value at index p+i
        int valP = (n>>(p+i))&1;
        // get binary value at index q+i
        int valQ = (n>>(q+i))&1;
        
        // if values are different, swap them
        if(valP != valQ)
        {
            int maskP = (1<<(p+i));
            int maskQ = (1<<(q+i));
            n = n^(maskP|maskQ);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Let's put this in an image:

```
n=10010101
p=0
q=4
k=4

   bit pos: 76543210
--------------------
i p+i q+i | 10010101
0  0   4  |    x   x // 1 and 1 : do nothing
          | 10010101
1  1   5  |   x   x  // 0 and 0 : do nothing
          | 10010101
2  2   6  |  x   x   // 1 and 0 : swap (xor with 01000100)
          | 11010001
3  3   7  | x   x    // 0 and 1 : swap (xor with 10001000)
          | 01011001
```

For code simplicity, I chose to move from least significant digit to most significant (*i.e.* right to left)

---

Other answer using the `swap_bit` proposed as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334412/7831383):

```
static int swap_bit(int n, int pos1, int pos2)
{
    if ((n>>pos1)&1) != ((n>>pos2)&1)
        n = n^((1<<pos1)|(1<<pos2));

    return n;
}

static void Main()
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        n = swap_bit(n, p+i, q+i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but isn't your solution specific for the number "n" that you've put? Maybe the way I have written the condition of the problem is unclear, but it is to swap the positions in any given number.

Comment: @MartinDeyanov nope, it should be working for any `int n`, I only chose these values for `n,p,q,k` because it showed the 4 possible cases when comparing bit values